# Incorrect alphabetical sort order in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I'm on Postgres 14.

The schema I'm using has the C.UTF-8 Collate, UTF8 Encoding and C.UTF-8 Ctype.

For some reason the query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name
```

where `column_name` is of type `varchar(25)`, will return this order:

```
A, B, C, D, ... a, b, c, d, ...
```

I have a hunch it has to do with UTF8's character table but I'm not too sure.

The preferred order would of course be:

```
A, a, B, b, C, c, D, d, ...
```

Does this have to do with how the schema is set up? And in either case, is there a way I can force it to have a custom order?